# Interactive 3d cross browser/platform/device

Tags: ios, 3d, cross-browser, webgl

Is there a way to display and manipulate a 3D image in a browser that will work in IE (without a plugin) and on the iPad? WebGL seems to be the best option and there are some server-side WebGL enablers for non-HTML5 supporting browsers, but seems no supprt on iOs. Flash is obviously out for a start.

Anyone had any experience? Use case is a 3D model of an object which the user can change colours of the sides via a web interface using javascript.

Appreciate any advice

MitchK

Answer (score 0):

Tried curve3D?

Firefox 3.6+, IE8+, Chrome 5+, Opera 10.5+

http://codi.st/pages/curve3d